# Keep null rows after filtering

Tags: sql, oracle

Before select
Status could be:
X1, X2, NULL

`SELECT * FROM surrtest t Where t.Status != „X2“`

It’s deleting also rows where Status was null. But it shouldn’t.

So after query I’m only getting rows where status Is X1 but I also want the NULL rows.

Is it possible?

I don’t know if it’s possible. If not maybe there is a workaround where we replace the null values with empty strings? But I hope it is possible without changing the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT * FROM surrtest Where Status != 'X2' or Status is null
```

If that doesn’t work then there’s something weird going on with your database.

In most databases, a **where** clause evaluates to either **true**, **false**, or **unknown**. Any comparison with `null` will result in an **unknown** result. Since a `where` clause filters out all records that don't evaluate to **true**, you will not see records that evaluate to **unknown**, as well as **false**.

In your original query, the `where` clause was filtering out `null` records, because they evaluated to **unknown**. So, you have to add the extra part `or Status is null` to the `where` clause to include the `null` records.

Also, do **NOT** use `or Status = null`, since that will always evaluate to **unknown**, like mentioned before. You **must** use `or Status is null`.

Comment: But why is it necessary to say OR Status is NULL? I mean why does it filtering out the null rows by default?

Comment: It's the same reason why you have to use `Status is null` rather then `Status = null`.
If you try to compare null values with `=` or `!=` or `<>` -- the result will always be null. E.g. `SELECT `X2` != null` does not yield `true` but `null`.

Comment: @Codernew I updated my answer with some information on why databases do this.